# How to make DataFrame from list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe

I have a list of tuples:

```
tup= [((1,1),(1,2)),((2,1),(2,2))]
```

Now I need to make a DataFrame of each instance of this tuple

```
pd.DataFrame(tup)

        0       1
0  (1, 1)  (1, 2)
1  (2, 1)  (2, 2)
```

However, I do want 4 columns like this:

```
   0  1  2  3
0  1  1  1  2
1  2  1  2  2
```

My skills in python are somewhat limited, but improving...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way using a list comprehension together with `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain

tup = [((1,1),(1,2)),((2,1),(2,2))]

df = pd.DataFrame([list(chain.from_iterable(i)) for i in tup])

print(df)

   0  1  2  3
0  1  1  1  2
1  2  1  2  2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just expand the tuples with a list comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[a, b, c, d] for ((a, b), (c, d)) in tup])
print(df)
```